# Fast way to categorize a list

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, google-apps-script

I'm trying to do the following in either python or javascript (whichever is faster):

1. Take as inputs i) a string, ii) an ordered list of lookups, and iii) a list of categories that correspond 1:1 with [ii]
2. Find the first element of [ii] that exists in [i]. In other words, if [i] is "tomato", I want to find the first element of [ii] that exists as a substring of [i]
3. return the corresponding element of [iii]

Today I'm doing something like this:

```
for element in [ii]:
   check if [ii] is a substring of [i]
   if yes, then:
      store the corresponding category from [iii]
      end loop
   else:
      continue loop
```

The problem with this is that when I'm doing this over a lot of strings (e.g., a list of things in item [i]) it takes a super long time.

Does anyone have an algorithm / approach that can make this faster?

Comment: You could try transforming `[ii]`s into a regular expression first, but I have no idea whether that'd be faster or slower - you could try it and see what happens.

Comment: Since this is google-apps-script, I'm assuming your talking about a script bound to a Spreadsheet for example?

Comment: I've worked with a 100,000 row Spreadsheet and looping through and comparing values in google app script has been as fast as a fraction of a second.

Comment: i'm looping through gCal events so can do this in GAS or in Python

Comment: Perhaps you can check [this resource](https://gist.github.com/DoctorDerek/cc97857f16f435102501b97b9253a0d2)

Comment: Please explain what gCal is.

Comment: So I found out gCal is just a colloquel name for Google Calendar.  Now explain where i, ii and iii come from.  How is this related to Google Calendar?  I wonder if the performance issue is due to repeated calls to Google Calendar similar to the getValue()/getValues() performance. of Google Sheets.